# Why can't I update TEXT type columns in Informix

Tags: .net, sql, informix

I face the following problem. I have some fields in my Informix database.  I decided to change these fields to TEXT type (BLOB) to allow large text. The problem is: when inserting new values, it works perfectly, but the problem when updating existing values is it doesn't work at all. What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should give a try with the CLOB datatype instead of BLOB, since you have text data. CLOB stands for Character Large OBject and BLOB for Binary Large OBject.

Comment: then if i use the CLOB data type , is the UPDATE statement syntax is the same and  put my text between single quote or double quote,,some one tell me to use lvarchar instead of BLOB it will allow to store 3k..

Comment: If 3k is sufficient for you it is OK. On the other hand Informix' CLOB allows you to store up to 4 terabytes in a CLOB.